# Android/java Not all Data written to text file is readable

Tags: java, android, io, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

Ok so i am attempting to retrieve a .txt file from a server, write it to a local file and then be able to recall it later.

I noticed that i was not able to read back the file after i copied it locally

At first i thought it was something wrong with my read back code as when i open the file in wordpad or wordpad++ the content is present and written correctly as far as i can tell to the file.

However after much testing i determined there was nothing apparently wrong with the read back code.

So i added a test, i added some static writes to the code that does the copying:

> bw.write("This is the test" + "\r\n");
>
> bw.write("My first line!" + "\r\n");
>
> bw.write("My second line ");
>
> bw.write("keeps going on...P" + "\r\n");

Now when i run it everything writes correctly to the file (or appears to) but during read back only the static writes above are read.

Even though i can visually see the content in the file, the stuff that was copied from the web based file is (although present) never read back.

Any help would be appreciated

This is the code i am using to read and copy the file
** This is the file i am reading from on the web
CrewAdviceMasterControlURL = http://lialpa.org/CM3/CrewAdvices/advice_master.txt

```
public static String GetMasterFileStream(String Operation) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String inputLine = null;

    URL AdviceMasterControl = new URL(CrewAdviceMasterControlURL);
    File outfile = new File("sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt");

    if(!outfile .exists()){
        outfile .createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outfile);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(AdviceMasterControl.openStream()));
    System.out.println("Creating the master");
    bw.write("This is the test" + "\r\n");
    bw.write("My first line!" + "\r\n");
    bw.write("My second line ");
    bw.write("keeps going on...P" + "\r\n");


        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(inputLine);   //for producing test output

            sb.append((inputLine + "\r\n"));
            bw.write(String.valueOf(inputLine) + "\r\n");
         }


    in.close();
    bw.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and this is the code i am using to read it back

```
public static String GetLocalMasterFileStream(String Operation) throws Exception {

String FullPath = "/sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt";
System.out.println("path is " + FullPath);
    File file = new File(FullPath);
      if (file.canRead() == true) {System.out.println("-----Determined that file is readable");}

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
line = br.readLine();
System.out.println("-----" + line);
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        System.out.println("-----" + line);   //for producing test output
        text.append('\n');

    }
    br.close();
    return text.toString();

}
```

Comment: Did you understand what you wrote? Because I did not.

Comment: ok edited for formatting a bit

Comment: I can only see what you write (which is also obvious by reading your code). But I can't see what you read (which should be the same). But if you get what you put... then it's working. If so, I can't get the meaning of this post.

Comment: The content that is read in from the .txt file on the web is read correctly because i can write it to the log. But for some reason when i write that same line of text to the .txt file i cannot then re-read it with code. However if i open notepad it is in the file. I suspect its some kind of formatting issue

Comment: Maybe it's only a different encoding. It happens, between Windows and Unix.

Comment: its really weird. The stuff that i write staticly using just a simple bw.write("random text here" + "\r\n");

can be read back fine and infact the first 3 lines which i write that way first as a test are read back fine. But anything written inside that while loop (which is text comming from the file on the web) cannot be read back by the program.

Even tough if i browse to the dir and open the file using file explorer the content is in the file

Comment: this is the file i am reading from btw
http://lialpa.org/CM3/CrewAdvices/advice_master.txt

Comment: Maybe I'm guessing what's happening: you want to open a file in **append** mode, to attach new content to it. Or you will overwrite its contents each time.

Comment: I want to overwrite the file each time.

Comment: I give up. I really can't understand what are we talking about.

Comment: There is a file on the server. I want to open it and copy it to the local storage. I am able to do this. I can open the file in word pad after it is copied and the content is there. When I try to open it using the second method I posted. All the buffered reader returns null content.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. The problem was with the txt file its self on the server. When the file was uploaded via FTP the ftp program was in auto. This seems to have forced the upload in binary instead of ASCII.

I re-uploaded in ASCII and it solved the problem.